# Why Virtual Memory Address is the same in different process?

Tags: c++, c, windows, virtual-memory

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGMsz.png]

I know the virtual memory separates 2G(for kernel)/2G(for user) in Windows.
But why the address of variable isn't stack continually?

Likes 0x22ff74,0x22ff78,0x22ff82,0x22ff86 ? Does it mean that Windows use sandbox mechanism in user process?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's exactly what virtual memory is. The operating system provides each program with its own private address space. In reality the operating system is in charge of mapping those virtual addresses back to the physical address space without the application being aware.

As you noticed this means that two applications can have different data residing at the same virtual address in the program.

Read more about virtual memory [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But more question confuse me after reading wiki you provide.Dose it means each process think that they own 2G entirely(or said each process have a new,empty and clean VAS)? If yes,is this the reason why four program start at same VAS Address ?  Another question is that DLL(third-party) copy its ".data" and ".code" to each process's VAS? sorry for asking too many question <3

Comment: @John: It's complicated.  Each process has its own clean VAS.  On startup each DLL (along with the process executable) is memory mapped into the process.  Shared DLLs normally start at the same address in all processes (so the pages used for them are shared).  When a virtual address is touched (executed, read or written), memory management copies (pages) the contents of that virtual address into memory.

Comment: Followup to previous answer: Sometimes DLL addresses collide, in which case the loader will relocate the DLL to a new address.  After this, the pages for the DLL will no longer be shared with other processes that use the DLL.

Comment: And one more followup: It's likely that this behavior won't be seen on Windows Vista and Windows 7 - that's because they have a feature called ASLR which "randomizes" the base address of all the DLLs.  So the address the DLLs are loaded at will change from one boot to another.

Comment: Now I understand a lot about Visual Memory Space! Thanks a lot guys! :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you confusing physical addresses and virtual addresses? It's ok for two processes to access the same virtual address, because each process see its own virtual memory space. On the other hand, all processes share the same physical memory space in the machine, so each process will have that same virtual address mapped to a different physical address (assuming there is no shared memory).

Answer (score 0):

Let me explicate it another way. Process X is running on machine A, and the same program is running as process Y on machine B. Does it matter if some global variable of your program takes same memory address on both machines? They are different! The same way, if that global variable is stored at XYZ location for one instance of process, another instance of process may have the same **virtual address** (XYZ) for that global variable.