# If different process have their own memory space, how could the address of local variable is the same?

Tags: c, process

From now on, I think after `fork()` is being called, the local variable is duplicated into parent process and child process, they are separated. But I try to fetch the address of each local variable in different process,it turns out that they are same:

```
int main(void){
  int local = 10;
  pid_t childPid;
  childPid = fork();
  if(childPid == 0 ){
    printf("[Child] the local value address is %p\n",&local);
  }else if(childPid < 0){
    printf("there is something wrong");
  }else{
    printf("[Parent] the local value address is %p\n",&local);
  }
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output is:

[Parent] the local value address is 0x7fff5277baa8
[Child] the local value address is 0x7fff5277baa8

Any idea about this?

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208421/why-virtual-memory-address-is-the-same-in-different-process may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being in a different "space" means that the "same" index point in different spaces does not refer to the same thing. Think of "spaces" as pieces of paper. "The 4th character of the 3rd line" on page 1 does not refer to the same thing as on page 2.

Comment: +1 Good illustration about virtual memory without the intimidating big terms

Comment: so does virtual memory store all the stack, Does global variable also store in virtual memory for each process?

Comment: The meaning of any address is per-process. Think of it logically as a two-dimensional array indexed by pid and the address in the process's memory space: `system[pid][address]`. Of course in reality it's not an array like this (and in fact due to shared memory maps, addresses in different processes can refer to the same underlying memory, even if they're not the same address in the process's address space) but this is at least worth something for understanding it conceptually.

Answer (score 2):

Because the memory space a process gets is **virtual**. That means the actual physical address on memory chips could be different. In the case you mentioned, local object addresses in two different processes are guaranteed to have different private physical address on memory chips. 
That being said, there are circumstances when two non-local object addresses from different processes map to the same physical address. Most commonly, that could be `shared library` or `shared memory`.
If you do not specify `position-indepedent-code` when compiling your `shared library`, you really could end up same virtual address map to same physical address when two concurrent processes use this `shared library`.

Comment: +1 for letting me know the `shared memory`